# KendoUI Grid filter for date and number

Tags: filter, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, angular5

I am building an Angular application. In my KendoUI Grid, EmployeeID and Total hours are numbering, not sure how to set the filter for them.
ReportDate which is stored in the format mm/dd/yyyy (03/16/2018), I am using filter="date" format="{0:d}" as given in an example on Telerik website, but with this filter, the date displays as 3/16/2018 instead of 03/16/2018 and filter doesn't get applied. Please guide how to correct format.

```
    <kendo-grid 
        [data]="gridData"
        [pageSize]="state.take"
        [skip]="state.skip"
        [sort]="state.sort"
        [filter]="state.filter"
        [sortable]="true"
        [pageable]="true"
        [filterable]="true"
        (dataStateChange)="dataStateChange($event)"
        [kendoGridBinding]="employees" 
        [height]="600" [group]="group" [pageable]="true" [pageSize]="10">
    <ng-template kendoGridToolbarTemplate>
        <button type="button" kendoGridExcelCommand>
      <span class="k-icon k-i-file-excel"></span>Export to Excel</button>
  </ng-template>
  <kendo-grid-column field="EmployeeID" title="Employee ID" [width]="150"></kendo-grid-column>
  <kendo-grid-column field="ReportDate" title="Report Date" width="240" filter="date" format="{0:d}" ></kendo-grid-column>
  <kendo-grid-column field="BeginTime" title="Begin Time"></kendo-grid-column>
  <kendo-grid-column field="EndTime" title="End Time"></kendo-grid-column>
  <kendo-grid-column field="TotalHours" title="Total Hours"></kendo-grid-column>
  <kendo-grid-column field="Approvedby" title="Approved by"></kendo-grid-column>
  <kendo-grid-column field="Timestamp" title="Time stamp"></kendo-grid-column>
 <kendo-grid-excel fileName="Report.xlsx" [fetchData]="allData"></kendo-grid-excel>
</kendo-grid>
```

Comment: have you tried parseFormat?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really get your question since it's solution may be just changing the format, so you wanted to it to be **03/16/2018**. Then
why dont you just change the format to `filter="date" format="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}`

as long as your ReportDate field is stored as **date** in the datasource it should work.

Example : taken from kendo example, i'm just slightly changing the format [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/whahedykKEQFfh6Fb4vL?p=preview)

Comment: This did change the filter to correct format, but KendoUI displays month as month+1 (you can see this in the sample you provided). I understand that in JavaScript month is 0 based array, but how to fix it?

Comment: why fix it? it just showed it in base 1 which is the common one, you wanted it to show it as base 0?

Comment: I think I didn't explain myself clearly. In the example you provided, for ProductId 1,  Date is defined as "FirstOrderedOn": new Date(1996, 8, 20), but is being displayed in grid as 20/09/1996 instead of 20/08/1996. How to fix that? https://imgur.com/a/FGpePgz

Comment: please check [this](https://plnkr.co/edit/vquVncDakTmZPcQCpT7u?p=preview). If we saved it as date, that behavior is to be expected. If you wanted the datasource data to be the same as what it showed on the UI then store it as string